# Maps API Memory Leak

Tags: android, api, dictionary, memory, memory-leaks

In my project I have MainActivity A (which handles app navigation), fragment 1 (gridview), fragment 2 (map).

I am calling map fragment from grid fragment (displaying marker for the selected entry) using callback in mainactivity, which replaces map fragment putting some args (for marker details).

Everything working so far, but after certain times calling the map fragment getting outofmemory exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 400 Process: XXX , PID: 2378
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4194316 byte allocation with 684253 free bytes and 668KB until OOM 
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)  
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:812)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:789) 
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:756)  
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.c.i.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.c.l.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.c.l.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.c.l.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.c.b.ak.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.c.b.as.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.x.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.l.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.l.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.cj.g(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.cj.run(Unknown Source)
```

Tried to temporarly remove bitmaps for map marker custom infowindow and so on, did not really affect. Memory increases and increases each time when replacing map fragment.

Any idea how to handle / to destroy old map, tried in several ways and looked at several issues, but did not find proper solution.

Comment: These exception is generally occurs only when you draw two maps simultaneously on the same layout..Check that are you calling create map method twice??

Comment: You can use [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to detect memory leaks.

Comment: you mean the getMapAsync() method? that is called only once in onResume. also tried to destroy map by map.clear() in onDestroy, but as read in other issues, that will have no effect.

Answer (score -1):

add this in your manifest file

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

For more information read this, 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Comment: if you are loading images in gridview then scale down image and load them that will reduced memory usage.

Comment: as i wrote, removed the bitmaps temporarly, did not solve the issue. even using picasso for the gridview images